# Z-Transform Poles and Zeros Locations on MATLAB

Tags: matlab, function, filter, transfer, digital

I am implementing an FIR Filter described as below:

```
y(n) = x(n) + 2x(n-1) + 4x(n-2) + 2x(n-3) + x(n-4)
```

Where there are no poles in this system.

Computing the transfer function on MATLAB yields `HZ = 1 + 2 z^-1 + 4 z^-2 + 2 z^-3 + z^-4` which is correct, but when I try to plot the Zeros locations I find a pole at the origin. However the impulse response of the system is correct, but it's only shifted to the right side by one. Why is this also happening ?

What I cannot figure out is, why there is a pole at the origin and why there are some zeros outside the unit circle.

```
close all;clear;clc;

Ts = 0.1;

num = [1, 2, 4, 2, 1];
den = 1;

HZ = tf(num, den, Ts, 'variable', 'z^-1')
```

[image: Pole zero map]

[image: impulse response]

```
figure(1)
pzplot(HZ)
axis equal

figure(2)
stem(impulse(HZ*Ts), 'linewidth', 1)
xlabel('n', 'FontSize', 13)
ylabel('h(n)', 'FontSize', 13)
title('Impulse Response')
grid minor
axis([0 10 0 max(num)+0.1])
```

Comment: FIR filters contain poles as many as their zeros but they are all located at the origin. Multiply the both num and den by the z^4

Comment: @percusse I understand what you mean, but your solution requires symbolic expressions, and I want to compute the numerical values.

Comment: invert your num and use den as `[1,0,0,0,0]` for example. You can also use filter commands of signal processing toolbox for this

Comment: @percusse You mean I use `'Z'` instead of `'z^-1'` ?

Comment: If you want the inverse powers of z then use `filt(num,den,0.1)`. it will do what you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your impulse response is `HZ = 1 + 2 z^-1 + 4 z^-2 + 2 z^-3 + z^-4` 
thus for `z = 0 i.e Origin` the impulse response is `infinity/undefined` and hence by convention `z=0` should be a pole.
And since your impulse response is 'Finite Duration' the `ROC` is `whole Z-Plain except 0` and ROC can contain Zeroes but not poles. Thus you have zeroes outside the unit circle.
Anyways you can always put HZ = 0 and compute values of Z ( the equation is of degree 4 there should be 4 values.)

Comment: The zeros outside makes the system unstable, however, it is a finite impulse system and in this example has to be a stable one.

Comment: I dont know about zeroes but i read that if ROC contains unit circle System should be stable.

Comment: Part of your answer is right, I read about stability and causality and found that stability counts only on poles either in or outside the unit circle. But I don't understand the pole at origin.

Comment: @OsamaAbbas, let see if i can clarify  _Pole is any point where the function becomes undefined/infinity_ right?. Now your `impulse response is HZ = 1 + 2 z^-1 + 4 z^-2 + 2 z^-3 + z^-4`. This is a geomentric progression with **5 terms and z^-1 as common ratio**. Now if we use the formula for Sum of G.P we get `HZ = (1 - z^5)/z^4(1-z)` now try to put `z=0` in this and see if you get infinity :) . You can always put `z=0 in HZ = 1 + 2 z^-1 + 4 z^-2 + 2 z^-3 + z^-4` and you'll still get `infinity` as `1*z^-1 at z = 0 equals 1*1/0 = infinity `

Comment: Your answer is somewhat conveniant, but I am sure that pole at the origin gives a very high gain, however the impulse response is not approaching infinity. Thus, the pole at the origin is plotted for a reason. If  you put your cursor over the pole at the origin, you can see it's charachtristics, the overshoot is NaN, which makes me say that your answer is somewhat conveniant.